# Permission denied on git clone command

Tags: git, repository

I have entered everything correctly:

```
$ git clone "ssh://blah/blah/blah.git"
```

it takes me to the next stage, i then enter the server access code and it says

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I have tried every possible password combination.

Comment: Is it a private repository?

Comment: Yes it is, i've been given the server access also @LukePeterson

Comment: Where is your repo hosted?

Comment: @LukePeterson Thank you, it works now, and i don't know where the repo was hosted. I tried various different versions of the password until the right password was entered, it was a stupid mistake between an l and a 1 and the more complicated font of where i was given confused it even more

Comment: No worries, I'm glad you've solved your problem.  :)